# not understanding the get() in webbrowser module

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-webbrowser

I came across  the following code:

```
linkElems = soup.select('.r a')
numOpen = min(5, len(linkElems))
for i in range(numOpen):
    webbrowser.open('http://google.com' + linkElems[i].get('href'))
```

Here I am not getting how they have used .get() 
with list as I know .get() is for dictionary only

The above snippent is from the program trying to open first five goole search results in browser

Answer (score 1):

I think each list element is a dictionary, which has a key called 'href'. So in essence what it is doing is that, for each element in linkElems in the range of numOpen, get the value of its 'href' key and append it to the 'http://google.com' url and then open it.